# Как убрать лишний отступ

Tags: html, css, style

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать этот отступ(выделенное оранжевым)?

Вот код:

pay.php:

```
   <div class="col-xs-2">
   <!-- small box -->
   <div class="xtrasmall-box" style="background-image: url(img/wm.png);">
   </div>
   </div><!-- ./col -->
```

style.css:

```
 .xtrasmall-box {
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 60%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: А при изменении строки `width: 60%;` ничего не меняется?

Comment: Дело в том что должно быть Width: 100%; а я его сократил до 60% чтобы получить нужный размер.Если его изменить меняется ширина.

Answer (score 3):

```
margin: 0;
```

PS: И ещё 20 символов, чтобы отправить ответ...

Comment: ничего не меняется

Comment: @Ersultan, тогда покажи достаточный кусок кода.

Comment: какой кусок именно отправить?

Comment: >width: 60%; вот это уберите display: inline-block; вот это поправьте

Comment: @FLCL , если убрать width то блоки с картинками исчезают

Comment: @Ersultan, в таком случае лучше поместите изображения в тег <img/>, я правда в своих проектах обычно делаю банеры в таких списках одинакового размера и указываю его в стиле для их класса

Comment: Кстати, попробуйте не менять display, возможно тогда картинку плющить не будет

Comment: @FLCL, Спасибо тебе,проблема решилась с использованием <img>,теперь еще проблема картинки прижались друг к другу,как между ними добавить пробел?

Comment: Проблему пробелов решил,все спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что это не отступ, а оставшееся место в контейнере. Если он вас смущает, то советую добавить класс к блоку .col-xs-2 и менять его ширину, а у блока .xtrasmall-box оставить ширину 100%

Answer (score -1):

задать width: 60%; не в процентах а в px.